# PL/SQL code to Retrieve a list of students who selected more than 4 courses

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am in the learning phase of PL/SQL, need help in retrieving this data;
Retrieve a list of students who selected more than 4 courses. If no students returned, the output must be “There are no students who selected more than 4 courses”. If there are such students, output their average grades.
I must also include exception handling in your script and must run a SQL statement to complete the task: return `studentID` paired with their average grade if they selected more than 4 courses.

This is my structure:

> Class (class_id, course_id)
>
> Enroll (student_id, class_id)
>
> Grade (student_id, class_id, score)

Comment: You can't possibly be using PL/SQL on SQL Server. Please fix the tags to reflect your environment correctly.

Comment: Do you have a specific technical question, or are you just asking to have your homework done for you? Does the course material not give you any clues at all on how to approach the assignment?

Comment: It might be easiest just to copy your classmate's version from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092475/perform-calculations-on-data-in-table-type?

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand your question. You must to make a function in PLSQL, and then you query the function?

To select the students who selected more than 4 courses, you must use the "group by" clause.
For example:

```
select student_id, count(*) courses 
from enroll
having courses > 4
group by student_id;
```